# Best approach for Spring+MyBatis with Multiple Databases to support failovers

Tags: java, spring, architecture, mybatis

I need to develop some services and expose an API to some third parties.
In those services I may need to fetch/insert/update/delete data with some complex calculations involved(not just simple CRUD). I am planning to use Spring and MyBatis.

But the real challenge is there will be multiple DB nodes with same data(some external setup will takes care of keeping them in sync). When I got a request for some data I need to randomly pick one DB node and query it and return the results. If the selected DB is unreachable or having some network issues or some unknown problem then I need to try to connect to some other DB node.

I am aware of Spring's AbstractRoutingDataSource. But where to inject the DB Connection Retry logic? Will Spring handle transactions properly if I switch the dataSource dynamically?

Or should I avoid Spring & MyBatis out-of-the-box integration and do Transaction management by myself using MyBatis?

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Why pick a database at random for each query? Why not use a single server until you actually realize something is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I propose to you using of NoSQL database like MongoDB. It is easy clustering. You can configure for example use 10 servers and do replication of data 3 times.

Thats mean that if 2 of your 10 servers will fails - you still got data save.

NoSQL databases is different comparing to RDBS, but they can give hight performance for clustering.

Also, there is no transactions support for NoSQL - you have to do it manually in case of financial operations.

Actually you should thing in different way when developing with NoSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I don't have a choice of moving to NoSQL for now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work. Get AbstractRoutingDataSource and code your own one. The only thing you cannot do is to change the target database while a transaction is running.

So what you have to do is putting the db retry code in the getConnection. If during the transaction that connection becomes invalid you should let it fail.

Comment: My requirement is a bit more complicated... i have to retry not only for connection failures but also if I can't get a lock on particular table, got some recoverable db exceptions. So I am designing an extension for AbstractRoutingDataSource to support all these retry mechanism. I will post this extension details on my blog www.sivalabs.blogspot.com once completed.